# deleting the consecutive rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
ClaimID ClaimStatusCode StatusDate
11,     Closed,         2010-05-10 12:19:00.000
11,     Open,           2010-05-25 09:30:00.000
11,     Closed,         2011-06-01 00:00:00.000
11,     Open,           2011-06-10 00:00:00.000
22,     Closed,         2011-03-14 00:00:00.000
22,     Open,           2011-05-04 00:00:00.000
33,     Closed,         2007-12-19 17:19:00.000
33,     Open,           2007-12-24 12:07:00.000
**33,   Open,           2008-09-08 15:36:00.000**
44,     Closed,         2008-11-19 17:19:00.000
44,     Open,           2008-12-24 12:07:00.000
44,     Closed,         2009-07-28 15:36:00.000
```

For any ClaimID, if Open claim status is follwed by open, then second Open status row is not required. That is every time Closed is follwed by Open.
Here Last row for ClaimID 33 with StatusDate 2008-09-08 15:36:00.000 is not required (starred for reference).
I tried using rownumber function, but no luck.

Answer should be:

```
ClaimID ClaimStatusCode StatusDate 
11,     Closed,         2010-05-10 12:19:00.000
11,     Open,           2010-05-25 09:30:00.000
11,     Closed,         2011-06-01 00:00:00.000
11,     Open,           2011-06-10 00:00:00.000
22,     Closed,         2011-03-14 00:00:00.000
22,     Open,           2011-05-04 00:00:00.000
33,     Closed,         2007-12-19 17:19:00.000
33,     Open,           2007-12-24 12:07:00.000
44,     Closed,         2008-11-19 17:19:00.000
44,     Open,           2008-12-24 12:07:00.000
44,     Closed,         2009-07-28 15:36:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used a `Cross Apply` to get the previous status for a row, and then checked when the prev status is the same as the current status:

```
delete ct
from
    claimtest ct
    cross apply (
        select top 1 prevstatus = ClaimStatusCode 
        from claimtest sub 
        where ct.claimid = sub.claimid and sub.statusdate < ct.statusdate 
        order by statusdate desc
    ) p
where 
    ct.ClaimStatusCode = p.prevstatus
```

Comment: yes this works for me. I got one more scenereo also with Claim ID 44 (i just edited), and your code works for that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT
       ClaimID, ClaimStatusCode, MIN(StatusDate)
    FROM
       Table
   GROUP BY
      ClaimID, ClaimStatusCode
   HAVING
      SUM(CASE claimID WHEN 'Open' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) <= 1
```

EDIT per yoru comment -- added the HAVING clause

PS -- this select gets your "good" records for you.  If you want to change it to get only the "bad" records (candidates for deletion, I assume), then use MAX instead of MIN, and use > 1 in the having clause.

Comment: If only it were that easy. This doesn't handle ClaimID = 11 where it has been Open, Closed, then Open again.

Comment: But it swill delete two records for ClaimID 11 also.

Comment: I see -- then use a HAVING clause to find the ones with too-many 'Open' statuses.  BTW -- per the example you gave, this doesn't look good, but I'm assuming (which you didn't put in your example) that the first record for every claim will be 'open', not 'closed'.